# How do I get class of a Ruby object in C?

Tags: c, ruby

I have a function that handles two types: `NVector` and `NMatrix`; the former is derived from the latter. This function is basically a specialized copy constructor. I want it to return an object of the same type as that upon which it was called, so, `NVector` returns `NVector`, not `NMatrix`.

```
static VALUE nm_init_modifiedcopy(VALUE self) {
  // ... some code ...

  // formerly, I had cNMatrix where klass is. But it could also be cNVector!
  return Data_Wrap_Struct(klass, mark_func, delete_func, unwrapped_self_copy);
}
```

How do I get the class property of an object to pass into `Data_Wrap_Struct`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like clockwork, as soon as I ask a question on Stackoverflow, I find the answer.

The macro is `CLASS_OF`.

```
static VALUE nm_init_modifiedcopy(VALUE self) {
  // ... some code ...

  return Data_Wrap_Struct(CLASS_OF(self), mark_func, delete_func, unwrapped_self_copy);
}
```

Comment: "Like clockwork, as soon as I ask a question on Stackoverflow, I find the answer." And what did we learn from that Dorothy? :-) Give yourself the selected answer when SO allows it.

Comment: I think that the accepted method is rb_class_of (CLASS_OF simply being a macro around that function)